# Can't use mongo command, shows command not found on mac

Tags: macos, mongodb

I'm using Mac Lion. I was using mongodb version 1.4. I wanted to upgrade to 1.8.5 and I followed http://shiftcommathree.com/articles/how-to-install-mongodb-on-os-x step wise replacing each mongodb-osx-x86_64-1.4.0 by mongodb-osx-x86_64-1.8.5. Everything goes smooth. I tried:

```
mongod
```

it's ok. I can access localhost:28017
but,

```
mongo
```

shows command not found

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Starting from Mongodb version 6.0 `mongo` was replaced by `mongosh`

Comment: Please give also credits to @dreameral for the comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/67995456/7646049

Comment: This is the right answer in 2022.

Comment: This worked for me. Seems to be the right answer

Comment: please accept this as the correct answer in 2022

Comment: worked for me on GCE instance

Answer (score 47):

Editing because this answer is now outdated: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74240679/683201

Original answer:
You need to add the path to "mongo" to your terminal shell.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mongodb/bin
```

Did you do the last step with paths.d? If so, try restarting your terminals.

Do you have a good reason for using 1.8.5? The current stable is 2.0.4, and it has many useful upgrades from 1.8.x

Comment: i add to path doing

    sudo sh -c 'echo "/usr/local/mongodb/bin" > /etc/paths.d/mongodb'  

I found the problem though. Another version was not deleted from Cellar. i found it after i searched     sudo find / -name mongod

and remove it... then follow all the process . I had backup for 1.8.5 so tried that... will install 2.0.4

Anyway thanks..

Comment: We have to run it in each terminal window, we intend to run mongo

Comment: @Saif you can add it to your `.bash_profile` or equivalent to make it run automatically.

Comment: I installed mongodb community 4.0 on Mac with Homebrew and the correct command in this case is 
`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/mongodb-community@4.0/bin`

Comment: what about when mongo resides in a docker container

Comment: For people who don't bother scrolling down in 2022, try `mongosh` instead of `mongo` before editing your path.

Answer (score 14):

### For readers in 2021:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/opt/mongodb-community@3.6/bin"
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction but this was the 2022 path for me:  `export PATH="$PATH:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community@4.2/4.2.19/bin"`

Comment: I installed mongodb 6.0 community edition, and there is not file "mongo" in this bin directory. So we still will get command not found even if we add this directory to the path.

Comment: @dreameral, did you find any solution yet?

Comment: @lonewolf Yes, for mongodb 6.0 the file is named "mongosh", so it's no longer "mongo" like it was in previous versions of mongo.

Answer (score 10):

You'll have to add the location of the Mongo binary to PATH.

Follow the steps below in order to make the PATH variable permanent:

1. Open Terminal and navigate to your user directory.
2. Run `touch ~/.bash_profile` and then  `open ~/.bash_profile`.
3. In TextEdit, add `export PATH="<mongo-directory>/bin:$PATH"` (Keep the quote marks - related to white spaces).
4. Save the `.bash_profile` file and Quit (Command + Q) Text Edit.
5. Run `source ~/.bash_profile`.
6. Run `echo $PATH` and check if the you see that the *Mongo binary* was added.

(*) Notice that the PATH variable is now available only for the current terminal and not to processes that were already started in the session. 
In order to make it available outside the current terminal -  you'll have to logout and login.

Answer (score 4):

1.Go to your [mongodb installation dir]:

```
cd <mongodb installation dir>
```

2.Type ./bin/mongo to start mongo:

```
./bin/mongo
```

[Read More](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/)

**Note :**

If above command gives error

*Failed global initialization: BadValue Invalid or no user locale set. Please ensure LANG and/or LC_* environment variables are set correctly.*

Run bellow command: [Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337557/badvalue-invalid-or-no-user-locale-set-please-ensure-lang-and-or-lc-environme)

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

How can find installation directory

```
find / -name "mongodb"
```

**You can also set path**

```
export PATH=$PATH:<mongodb installation dir>/bin
```

Answer (score 3):

[documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#ensure-the-location-of-the-binaries-is-in-the-path-variable)

```
export PATH={mongodb-install-directory}/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 3):

In Mac:

Go into Bash Profile:

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Add Path of Installation of MongoDB:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/mongodb-community@4.2/bin
```

Reload the Bash Profile:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate to the mongo directory using the command line and then start MongoDB with

```
./mongodb
```

I was facing the same problem this worked for me.

Comment: Any hint why this work? It did work for me too because I couldn't run 'mongod' while within the bin directory that contained the mongod executable. Only ./mongodb worked even thought I searched for another folder that could have the mongod executable but didn't find any. I did a npm mongod driver installation previously. I don't know if that is interfering with the launching of the mongod server. Trying to execute ./mongod outside of the containing folder didn't work neither.

Answer (score 1):

you need to install mongodb shell to ge the mongo command working.

Download [link](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have the right mongo command line tools installed. This from Brew worked for me though.

`brew install mongodb-community`

Answer (score 1):

so after installing mongoDB and shell, the bash command is

```
mongosh
```

instead of

```
mongo
```

**in the version 6.0 or newer.** if that still doesnt work, try resetting your pc. That worked for me. also try not using multiple download methods since it may cause issues on your machine

Comment: This is already covered by existing answers

Answer (score 0):

just a little recommandation, if your path has a space just wrap the whole path with quote or doublequote
example : C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2 . notice the space in "Program Files"

```
export PATH=$PATH:"C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/X.X/bin"
```