# installing mongo db using npm install --save mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, npm, installation

I am trying to install MongoDB on my personal machine for a Node project through the command line using npm install --save mongodb.  MongoDB shows up in the dependencies in my package.json file with a current version, but when I run mongodb -v, mongod, or just try to open up the mongo shell by running "mongo" I get these errors:

```
"command not found: mongodb"
"command not found: mongod"
"command not found: mongo"
```

I have also tried running sudo mongod to no avail.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  I have looked at a lot of documentation at this point and am not sure where to turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're just installing the node.js driver for Mongodb.  npm is generally used as a package manager solely for node.js packages and dependencies.  You need to install the actual database system using the binaries or a binary package installer e.g. [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840354/npm-install-g-mongodb-not-installing-mongodb-globally-on-osx-10-8-4), and looks like your same issue.

Comment: Thanks!  Installing mongodb through Homebrew seems to have gotten me part of the way there.  However when I try to run mongod in the project directory, it starts up and then terminates, giving me this error:  "I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating" , and for some reason when I run mongodb -v it still says "command not found: mongodb".  I installed it at first in my home directory and and currently am getting these errors with it installed in my project directory.

Comment: check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948789/mongodb-mongod-complains-that-there-is-no-data-db-folder