# BadValue Invalid or no user locale set. Please ensure LANG and/or LC_* environment variables are set correctly

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

When I run `mongo`, I get the warning:

> Failed global initialization: BadValue Invalid or no user locale set. Please ensure LANG and/or LC_* environment variables are set correctly.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Generating locales

Missing locales are generated with locale-gen:

```
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

Alternatively a locale file can be created manually with localedef:[1]

```
localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
```

Setting Locale Settings

The locale settings can be set (to `en_US.UTF-8` in the example) as follows:

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

The `dpkg-reconfigure locales` command will open a dialog under Debian for selecting the desired locale. This dialog will not appear under Ubuntu. The [Configure Locales in Ubuntu](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Configure_Locales_in_Ubuntu) article shows how to find the information regarding Ubuntu.

Comment: This did it for me on a raspberry: sudo localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
Thank you!!

Answer (score 357):

you can use the below command on terminal

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

Comment: To have it in all seasons : echo "export LC_ALL=C" >> ~/.bashrc

Comment: Only execute on your terminal. not server

Comment: This way just for current seesion, Just for one time, Not for forever!

Comment: hi, I have accidently downvoted this question and missed it. Now I cannot remove it. It says my vote is locked. I 'am really sorry. If there is any other way, let me know.

Comment: For those wondering: What does “LC_ALL=C” do? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do

Answer (score 33):

```
vim /etc/default/locale
```

add to it:

```
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: The other answers are not permanent solutions. We have to enter those commands each time we connect. Edit that file only once is the perfect solution! Thank you

Comment: This is the only permanent solution that worked for me. Definitely deserves more upvotes!

Comment: Worked. Importing thing to note is that you need to logout and login again in order for this to work.

Answer (score 25):

### Amazon Linux AMI

#### Permanent solution for ohmyzsh:

```
$ vim ~/.zshrc
```

Write there below:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Update changes in current shell by: `$ source ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 24):

adding the following lines to my **/etc/environment** file worked

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: How to save this file?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the missing local lang helper: for me the missing ones where de_LU de_LU.UTF-8 . Mongo 2.6.4 worked wihtout mongo 2.6.5 throw an error on this

Comment: Thanks! http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Perl_warning_Setting_locale_failed_in_Debian