# Failed global initialization: BadValue Invalid or no user locale set. Please ensure LANG and/or LC_* environment variables are set correctly

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, server

I have a problem to generate the locales on the serveur herbert and homer .
I run mongo I get the warning

```
Failed global initialization: BadValue Invalid or no user locale set. Please ensure LANG and/or LC_* environment variables are set correctly.
```

When I run

`dpkg-reconfigure locales`

mongo start successful , then  When reboot the server and run mongo i have the same problem.

Thank for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BadValue Invalid or no user locale set. Please ensure LANG and/or LC\_\* environment variables are set correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337557/badvalue-invalid-or-no-user-locale-set-please-ensure-lang-and-or-lc-environme)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/536875/error-in-installing-mongo-in-virtual-machine:

> Looks like your locale settings are broken or non-existent on that VM,
>   or at least that session on that VM. One of MongoDB's dependencies
>   (boost) will fail when a locale is not correctly set (see
>   SERVER-9032). For reference, before the change in SERVER-9032 this
>   problem still happened but looked like this.
>
> Sometimes logging out and back in can fix it (only broken for current
>   session), or you can try running sudo local-gen to make sure
>   generation is successful.
>
> In the meantime, as a workaround to get mongo (or mongod etc.)
>   running, just set your LC_ALL variable manually before starting the
>   program:

```
export LC_ALL=C
mongo
```

Comment: Then how do I fix the problem with my locale settings- I am on Freya Beta1