# Unable to run mongod inside ubuntu docker container through ssh (Docker is started using "--net=host")

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ssh, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I referred to many links to solve this error `SEVERE: Failed global initialization: BadValue Invalid or no user locale set. Please ensure LANG and/or LC_* environment variables are set correctly.`.

I executed `export LC_ALL=C`
as told in the below link

[Failed global initialization: BadValue Invalid or no user locale set. Please ensure LANG and/or LC_* environment variables are set correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375137/failed-global-initialization-badvalue-invalid-or-no-user-locale-set-please-ens)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/536875/error-in-installing-mongo-in-virtual-machine

I also referred  to [BadValue Invalid or no user locale set. Please ensure LANG and/or LC_* environment variables are set correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337557/badvalue-invalid-or-no-user-locale-set-please-ensure-lang-and-or-lc-environme)

and did the following steps,

```
root@product:/# localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
root@product:/# export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
root@product:/# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
root@product:/# export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
root@product:/# locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
root@product:/# dpkg-reconfigure locales
Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
```

After trying all the above steps also i still get the below error when i execute mongo command through ssh

```
product@product:~/docker$ sshpass -p password ssh root@172.20.71.71 'mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ &'
2015-02-24T09:50:27.158+0000 SEVERE: Failed global initialization: BadValue Invalid or no user locale set. Please ensure LANG and/or LC_* environment variables are set correctly.
```

But when i execute `mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ &` from within the container it works, below is the terminal output

```
root@product:/# mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ &
[1] 284
root@product:/# 2015-02-24T09:56:42.108+0000 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=284 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb/ 64-bit host=product
2015-02-24T09:56:42.108+0000 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.7
2015-02-24T09:56:42.108+0000 [initandlisten] git version: a7d57ad27c382de82e9cb93bf983a80fd9ac9899
2015-02-24T09:56:42.108+0000 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build7.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-02-24T09:56:42.108+0000 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-02-24T09:56:42.108+0000 [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb/" } }
```

If anyone knows why this is happening, I want to run it through ssh.

Comment: can you post th result from `sshpass -p password ssh root@172.20.71.71 'echo $LANGUAGE' `

Comment: Empty line is the response i get when i run your command. This is what i'm running= "product@product:~/docker$ sshpass -p password ssh root@172.20.71.71 'echo $LANGUAGE'"

Answer (score 2):

Probably your ssh client is trying to set those environmental variables in remote host. Edit you `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` commenting the line `SendEnv LANG LC_*`