# How to login to mongodb console in server

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm trying to create a new collection in an already existing mongodb database on an ubuntu server. I tried running the command mongod but it says the mongod not found

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your mongo server is running:

you can start using command `sudo service mongod restart` . Once it started just type `mongo` , It will take you in mongo console.

Answer (score 0):

Try `mongo`.

`mongod` is the one that starts the server. `mongo` is the client that connects to the server.

If your environment variable is set correctly, it should work.

If it still says command not found, try `/usr/bin/mongo`

You can find more info here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/

Comment: I got following error when try mongo       Failed global initialization: BadValue Invalid or no user locale set. Please ensure LANG and/or LC_* environment variables are set correctly.

Comment: For that, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375137/failed-global-initialization-badvalue-invalid-or-no-user-locale-set-please-ens

I wont include it in my answer as that was not the issue in your question. You were just trying wrong command.

Comment: Note that using `export` will just set the variable temporarily. You can either put that in `/etc/environment` or set that everytime you start `mongo`.

Comment: @karthikavnair if it has solved your issue, can you please accept it as answer?