# Can't use Mongo show commands, getting 'show: command not found' errors

Tags: mongodb

I have Mongo running but can't use the mongo commands. When I type `show collections` I get the error `show: command not found`.

How can I fix this?

I installed with homebrew so my mongo installation is at: `/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.0.6` and my databases are at `/data /db`.

I searched around but couldn't find an answer.

The following didn't help:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203589/cant-use-mongo-command-shows-command-not-found-on-mac

Comment: Did you mean to use the nodejs tag?

Comment: hmmm... you're right, deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, lol. I have to open the Mongo shell (by typing `mongo` into the terminal) and not just start the database using `mongod` as I had already done. Well ok then... my problem is solved.

Comment: Starting from Mongodb version 6.0 mongo was replaced by mongosh