# How to install command show

Tags: mongodb, terminal

I just install mongodb, I want to run

```
show dbs
```

I got

```
    Command 'show' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install mailutils-mh  # version 1:3.7-2.1, or
sudo apt install mmh           # version 0.4-2
sudo apt install nmh           # version 1.7.1-6
```

I follow, one by one, sudo apt install: mmh, nmh, mailulits-mh

that command show me alots package, but when I write

```
show db
```

I still get the same notice that: command 'show' not found

I do in this page

[Can't use Mongo show commands, getting 'show: command not found' errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37950954/cant-use-mongo-show-commands-getting-show-command-not-found-errors)

I read, and I follow to run mongodb, instead of mongo

I write again, it still give me the same point at first

ho to solve it dude, may be you have been there, I can teach me to solve

Answer (score 0):

In general, first you need do access the MongoDB shell after you can use the commands.

1 - Install using the official documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

2 - So, first you must invocate the MongoDB shell:

```
mongosh
```

[image]

3 - After you can use:

```
show dbs
```

[image]