# Trouble setting up Sublime Text 3 to work with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sublimetext3, mean-stack

- OS: Mac OS X Yosemite
- Installed MongoDB using Homebrew

I get the following error when I try to initiate build on sublime

```
/bin/sh: mongo: command not found
```

This is what my mongodb build file in sublime looks like

```
{
    "selector": "source.js",
    "shell":true,
    "cmd": ["mongo < ${file}"],
    "working_dir" : "/data/db"
}
```

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10204195/2442831

Comment: 'mongo' works in the terminal. but i can't access it from sublime text 3

Comment: try to launch sublime text from command line with `subl` command. Does it help?

Comment: Seems like it is working now. Changed the "cmd" to the path where mongo is installed. "cmd": ["/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.2.7/bin/mongo < ${file}"],